# automated backups for Aurora Serverless PgSQL cluster v2 for longer period

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

As per the AWS documentation of Aurora pgsql cluster, You can specify a backup retention period, from 1 to 35 days, when creating or modifying a DB cluster.

Is there any way to keep this backup for longer duration and store to S3 or in archival.

Comment: You can take a snapshot and export it to S3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-export-snapshot.html

Answer (score 0):

In the Snapshots window in the console, you see a set of tabs:

Manual
System
Shared with me
Public
Backup service
Exports in Amazon S3

The retention interval applies to the auto-generated snapshots in the "System" tab. If you pick one of the snapshots in there, do Actions -> Copy, and keep the AWS Region the same, the new snapshot will appear in the "Manual" tab. Those manual snapshots don't expire. (You do get charged for the storage once the retention interval expires.)

I like the "Export Snapshot Data to S3" feature for bringing the data into some other type of system that can read Parquet files. But because that type of exported data can't easily be re-imported back into Aurora, I don't consider it a way to keep a permanent version of the actual snapshot.

The snapshot represents all the views, indexes, column types, etc. so it has everything from the original cluster. It's not a "thing" though that you can get in the form of a file. If you want to have something to store in textual format long-term, independent of AWS, that would be a logical backup via pg_dump or mysqldump.